# Python3 Django Webapp HTML Test Button to print debug data

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, button, web-applications

I am writing a Django web app with python 3 and I would like to add an html button that when clicked prints debug data while I'm testing. I can start successfully run my web app, but I can't seem to figure out how to get my test class to run when I click my html button.

My index.html:

```
<!-- this form portion is the important part, everything else works -->
<form action='actionUrl' method='GET'>
<button id="runScript_btn" type="button" style="height:100px;width:100px" action={{test}}>{{test.x}}</button>
</form>
```

My Models.py:

```
class test:
    x = 1
    def printer(self):
        self.x+=1
        print(self.x)
        return self.x
```

Comment: Like everything else, you need a URL and a view that calls your method and returns a response with the result.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you. I am new to this, so could you provide an example?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-3